# Find out what Product each Employee has sold the most of

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find out what product each employee has the sold the most of (what is there favourite product to sell).

I have three tables, Sales (which has Quantity, Price and Product columns), Products & Employees, I know this can be done through the use of aggregates but can’t figure out the logic. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    E.EmployeeID,
    FirstName,
    ProductID,
    SUM(Quantity) AS S,
    MAX(Quantity) AS M
FROM    
    tbl_Employees AS E
INNER JOIN
    tbl_Sales AS S ON E.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID
GROUP BY
    ProductID, E.EmployeeID, FirstName
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the RDBMS? Also, sample data and table will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally doing this using ANSI standard window function:

```
select s.*
from (select s.EmployeeID, s.ProductId, sum(s.quantity) as quantity,
             row_number() over (partition by s.EmployeeID order by sum(s.quantity) desc) as seqnum
      from tbl_sales s
      group by s.EmployeeID, s.ProductId
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: That's the one Gordon. Thanks for your time.